# Can't add warp.ly's cordova plugin

Tags: cordova

I am trying to use warp.ly in my ionic app. So, I looked into their documentation and download it from [here](http://devs.warp.ly/#downloads).

When I run command to add this plugin to my app it shows error.

> Error: Invalid Plugin! /home/webber/Desktop/warply/warply_phonegap_sdk needs a valid package.json

[Error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n01Q2.png)

Can anybody please suggest me how should I solve this error?

Thank You.

Comment: I added the error directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add a `package.json` file to the donwloaded plugin or you can install it with the `--nofetch` flag:

```
cordova/phonegap plugin add <path/to/local/plugin> --nofetch
```

Since cordova 7.0.0 `npm install` is run by default when adding a new plugin which causes an error if no `package.json` is present. You can find the release notes for cordova 7.0.0 [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html).

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help you out!